# ¿Cómo guardar en bytes una imagen en android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, android-imageview

Tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy haciendo un ejemplo de cargar una imagen y previsualizarla en un `ImageView` en `Android Studio`. Y lo que deseo es convertir la imagen en bytes para poder guardarlo en base de datos.

Scripts

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private Button btnCapturar;
    private ImageView imgCapturado;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imgCapturado = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCapturada);
        btnCapturar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCapturar);
        btnCapturar.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/");
        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent,"Seleccione la aplicación"),10);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
            Uri path = data.getData();
            imgCapturado.setImageURI(path);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: es una mala práctica guardar bytes en una base de datos. En su lugar deberías guardar la uri

Comment: Lo mismo digo, pero ellos requieren que se guarde en base de datos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba esto. Usé webp porque es el formato que menos espacio ocupa, aunque de todos modos vas a tener archivos gigantes a menos que le bajes la resolución

```
private byte[] convertToBytes(Uri path) {
        Bitmap.CompressFormat format = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 30 ?
                Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP_LOSSLESS : Bitmap.CompressFormat.WEBP;
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(path);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            bitmap.compress(format, 100, outputStream);
            return outputStream.toByteArray();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Insisto en que almacenes la uri en vez de los bytes. Y si realmente necesitas los bytes, no los guardes en una base de datos sino en un almacenamiento diseñado específicamente para eso como [Cloud Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage)

Comment: Gracias, por tu apreciación afirme lo mismo pero bueno ellos desean que se guarde en bd.

Comment: Disculpen caballeros, veo q el problema que resolvieron es similar al que estoy lidiando yo, les agradeceria su ayuda por favor, -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/464493/como-puedo-convertir-la-imagen-de-una-foto-a-bytes-en-android