# ¿Como puedo convertir la imagen de una foto a bytes en Android?

Tags: javascript, android, android-studio

Tuve un largo problema desde un error para llamar a la camara del celular el cual no requeria permisos para su ejecucion hasta ahora que al tomar la foto quiero convertirlo en bytes para mandarlo por un array para que se guarde, me aparece el siguiente error en android,

Codigo ANDROID

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(resultCode != CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE){
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 50, stream);
            byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0,
                    byteArray.length);

            imgvoucher.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            Log.e(TAG,"EL VALOR DE ARRAY ES" + byteArray.toString());

            listFilesProp();
        }
    }


 private void  listFilesProp(){

    Global.xxpathfileimagen="";
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    String xnamefile;
    //obtiene ruta donde se encuentran los archivos.

    File dcim = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

    Log.e(TAG,"DCIM " + dcim.getAbsolutePath());
    String path=dcim.getAbsolutePath();
    path=path + "/Camera";
    xPathDir=path;

    File f = new File(path);
    //obtiene nombres de archivos dentro del directorio.
    File file[] = f.listFiles();
    for (int i=0; i < file.length; i++)
    {
        Log.d("Files", "Archivo : " + file[i].getName());
        //Agrega nombres de archivos a List para ser agregado a adapter.
        if(i==file.length-1) {
            xnamefile = file[i].getName();
            list.add(file[i].getName());
            Log.e(TAG,"EL ARCHIVO A TRANSPORTAR ES " + path + "/" + xnamefile );
            xPathFile=path + "/" + xnamefile;
            Global.xxpathfileimagen=path + "/" + xnamefile;
            comprimir(path + "/" + xnamefile);
        }
    }
}

   public void comprimir(String xpath) {

   int compressionRatio = 2; //1 == originalImage, 2 = 50% compression, 4=25% compress
   File file = new File (xpath);
   try {
       Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (file.getPath ());
       bitmap.compress (Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 50, new FileOutputStream (file));
   }
   catch (Throwable t) {
       Log.e("ERROR", "Error compressing file." + t.toString ());
       t.printStackTrace ();
   }

   Log.e(TAG, "comprimi ok");

}
```

Error que aparece al dar aceptar despues de haber tomado la foto

```
  E/SISTEMA: EL VALOR DE ARRAY ES[B@40360a6 E/SISTEMA: DCIM
/storage/emulated/0/DCIM D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pe.com.bitxense.appmartellentregas, PID: 16277
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=Intent {
act=inline-data flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity
{pe.com.bitxense.appmartellentregas/pe.com.bitxense.appmartellentregas.frmentregar}:
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5230)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5271)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
        at pe.com.bitxense.appmartellentregas.frmentregar.listFilesProp(frmentregar.java:570)
        at pe.com.bitxense.appmartellentregas.frmentregar.onActivityResult(frmentregar.java:518)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8292)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:5223)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5271) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) 
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075) 
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 16277 SIG: 9 Connected to process
17122 on device 'samsung-sm_a105m-R58M946VQJE'. Capturing and
displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be
disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings
page. I/martellentrega: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared
library. I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization
unsuccessful D/PhoneWindow: forceLight changed to true [] from
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.updateForceLightNavigationBar:4238
com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.updateColorViews:1494
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.dispatchWindowAttributesChanged:3216
android.view.Window.setFlags:1148
com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow.generateLayout:2444 
I/MultiWindowDecorSupport: updateCaptionType >> DecorView@b123304[],
isFloating: false, isApplication: true, hasWindowDecorCaption: false,
hasWindowControllerCallback: true D/MultiWindowDecorSupport:
setCaptionType = 0, DecorView = DecorView@b123304[] W/martellentrega:
Accessing hidden method
Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z
(greylist, reflection, allowed) W/martellentrega: Accessing hidden
method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V
(greylist, reflection, allowed) E/SISTEMA: DATOS NO VALIDO
```

Una ayuda pronta si saben del tema porfavor